# Display Json objects in paragraph in REACT

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am currently trying to put a transcript for an audio. The problem is that I am not able to put the JSON string in a paragraph format instead it is coming in different lines. My code is below

```
const transcript = (props) => {
  return (
      trans.word_timings[0].map(element => {
      return(
      <div className = "DisplayTextColored">
      <pre className = "TextSize">{element.word} </pre>
      </div>
      )
      })
  )
}
```

And my JSON file is

```
"word_timings": [

      {
        "startTime": "2.400s",
        "endTime": "2.800s",
        "word": "This"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "2.800s",
        "endTime": "3s",
        "word": "is"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "3s",
        "endTime": "3.400s",
        "word": "Brian"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "3.400s",
        "endTime": "3.900s",
        "word": "Isaacson"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "3.900s",
        "endTime": "4.100s",
        "word": "with"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "4.100s",
        "endTime": "4.500s",
        "word": "Guardian"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "4.500s",
        "endTime": "4.500s",
        "word": "mortgage"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "4.500s",
        "endTime": "5.400s",
        "word": "company"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "5.400s",
        "endTime": "5.700s",
        "word": "at"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "5.700s",
        "endTime": "5.900s",
        "word": "the"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "5.900s",
        "endTime": "6.100s",
        "word": "sound"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "6.100s",
        "endTime": "6.200s",
        "word": "of"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "6.200s",
        "endTime": "6.300s",
        "word": "the"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "6.300s",
        "endTime": "6.500s",
        "word": "tone,"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "6.500s",
        "endTime": "6.900s",
        "word": "please"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "6.900s",
        "endTime": "7.200s",
        "word": "leave"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "7.200s",
        "endTime": "7.300s",
        "word": "your"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "7.300s",
        "endTime": "7.600s",
        "word": "name"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "7.600s",
        "endTime": "8.200s",
        "word": "phone"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "8.200s",
        "endTime": "8.300s",
        "word": "number"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "8.300s",
        "endTime": "8.600s",
        "word": "and"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "8.600s",
        "endTime": "8.700s",
        "word": "a"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "8.700s",
        "endTime": "8.800s",
        "word": "brief"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "8.800s",
        "endTime": "9s",
        "word": "message,"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "9s",
        "endTime": "9.600s",
        "word": "and"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "9.600s",
        "endTime": "10s",
        "word": "I"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "10s",
        "endTime": "10s",
        "word": "will"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "10s",
        "endTime": "10.400s",
        "word": "return"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "10.400s",
        "endTime": "10.600s",
        "word": "your"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "10.600s",
        "endTime": "10.900s",
        "word": "call."
      },
      {
        "startTime": "10.900s",
        "endTime": "11.400s",
        "word": "Thank"
      },
      {
        "startTime": "11.400s",
        "endTime": "11.500s",
        "word": "you."
      }
]
```

I want to display each word in a paragraph but the words are being displayed in different lines. Also i don't want to use redux or so, only react-native for this purpose. Could anyone help me out with this, Thanks in advance .

Comment: Could you add a picture of what you want?

Comment: Do you mean you want ALL the words in a single paragraph? If so you'll need to change your `<div/>` to an inline element, or apply inline display CSS to it.

Comment: *I want to display each word in a paragraph but the words are being displayed in different lines*. Do you mean all the words in a single paragraph or each word in its own paragraph?

Comment: Use this -> return trans.word_timings.map(element => (<span className="TextSize">{element.word}&nbsp;</span>));

Comment: I want all the words to be displayed in single paragraph only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to map over the first item in your list instead of the list itself. Remove the `[0]` and it should work as expected:

```js
return trans.word_timings.map(element => (
  <div className="DisplayTextColored">
    <pre className="TextSize">{element.word}</pre>
  </div>
));
```

Live Example:

[image: Edit twilight-cache-izoup]

> I want to display each word in a paragraph but the words are being
>   displayed in different lines.

If you meant to put all the words into a sigle paragraph it may be better to first join them into a complete sentence and render that into a paragraph:

```
const transcript = (props) => {
  const sentence = trans.word_timings.map(timing => timing.word).join(' ');

  return <p>{sentence}</p>
}
```

Live Example:

[image: Edit peaceful-bose-4dbco]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I wanted Thanks